# Whose derelict ship do Boimler and Mariner find?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship, object-identification, star-trek-lower-decks

In LD: *Where Pleasant Fountains Lie*, Ensigns Boimler and Mariner [find a crashed starship](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ynbA581i5Y) that AGIMUS tries to influence them to salvage.

I've watched and rewatched this scene and can't quite figure out whose starship it is they find. Since Boimler seems to be so intimately aware of the systems to the extent that he can immediately identify the controls for the dimmer switch, I thought it was probably a Federation ship, but it also seems interesting that neither officer mentions the name or history of the ship, and the deceased captain looks more Cardassian (neck scales, vaguely Cardassian uniform). The language on the environmental controls station doesn't look anything like Cardassian (or Klingon, for that matter). This doesn't prove anything, though, since the console could have been [set](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/91034/70477) to whatever language the officer who last used it preferred.

Are there enough signs in the episode or elsewhere to determine what faction or nation the ship belongs to? Does the layout of the ship match something we've seen elsewhere in Star Trek?

Comment: Boimler's ability to locate the dimmer switch may just be a joke referencing how in the other TV shows Star Fleet crew are amazingly effective at understanding completely alien consoles.  There have been many cases where someone from Star Fleet sits down at a completely alien console and says something like "power, attitude...this must control the docking clamps...ok I'm ready to fly this alien space ship after 10 seconds with a panel full of unlabeled controls".